# python wait for job is done

Tags: python, wait

I have a script that calls several sql queries, some of which are heavy:

1. Calculation on 150 000 objects on a temporary table (can take
   several seconds)
2. Update the main table
3. Deletes the temporary table

I get an error message at level 2 (update) telling me that the relationship does not exist.

Does python wait for each process to finish or should I specify?

Comment: Can you share a [mre] so it's clearer what's happening?

Comment: Please post your current code and an MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example)